# Simple automated image changer malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple image changer that swaps between 2 images by a very simple bit of jQuery but for reasons unknown, probably lack of sleep, I cannot get it to work as wanted.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rws8c/) to see what's going on.

Here's the js;
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
function swap() {
    $('#display').attr('id', 'hidden').hide();
    $('#hidden').attr('id', 'display').fadeIn(500);

}


setInterval(swap, 2000);



});
```

Thanks!

Comment: you always hiding the hidden id and then fading in the display id, there isn't actually a swap going on? maybe use a class and toggle its display?

Comment: You change the `id` of the tag with `'display'` to `'hidden'`, and then when you try `$('#hidden')`, there are two tags with the same `id`. That is why you have a problem. If you use a temp variable to hold the previous `$('hidden')` before changing `$('display')`, there should be no problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Rws8c/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fadeToggle is indeed the best solution, but another solution could be something like this.
If you want to add some extra logic to the toggle next to your hide and fadein.

```
 function swap() {
    if($("#display").is(":visible"))
    {
         $('#display').hide();
         $('#hidden').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else
    {
         $('#display').fadeIn(500);
         $('#hidden').hide();
    }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rws8c/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is this about what you're looking to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    function swap() {
        $('#display').fadeToggle(500);
        $('#hidden').fadeToggle(500);

    }


    setInterval(swap, 2000);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a slightly different approach that enables you to easily add more than 2 images:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Define a single img element -->
<img src="http://musicglue-profile-pages.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/NiceandSlezzy.png" alt="The Tin Pigeons" title="The Tin Pigeons" id="display">
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// create an array that contains a entry for each img src. For more images, just add additional array entries. 
var images = ['http://musicglue-profile-pages.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/NiceandSlezzy.png',
              'http://musicglue-profile-pages.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/La-Route-Du-Rock1.jpg'];
    var curImage=images.length-1;
    var $image = $('#display');

    function swap() {
        $image.hide().attr('src', images[curImage]);
        if (curImage==images.length-1) {
            curImage=-1
        }
        curImage++;
        $image.fadeIn(500)
    }

    setInterval(swap, 2000);

});
```